# ValidationException when Connecting to redshift serverless from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, boto3, amazon-redshift-serverless

Simple python code to connect to lambda using boto3 API:

```
print('boto3 version: ' + boto3.__version__)
redshift = boto3.client('redshift-data')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  print('Preparing query')

  response = redshift.batch_execute_statement(
      Database='dev',
      Sqls=[
          '<<SQL QUERY>>'
      ],
      StatementName='get view'
  )
  print('Query executed '+ response)
```

This script gives the following error when run:

```
boto3 version: 1.20.32    
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the     BatchExecuteStatement operation: Either ClusterIdentifier or WorkgroupName needs to be     specified.",
  "errorType": "ValidationException",
  "requestId": "6aebba50",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 13, in lambda_handler\n    response = redshift.batch_execute_statement(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

This error does not make sense to me since the lambda uses [boto3-1.20.32 botocore-1.23.32](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html) and according to [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.20.32/reference/services/redshift-data.html#RedshiftDataAPIService.Client.batch_execute_statement), this version of boto3 does not have the WorkgroupName argument:

> When connecting to a serverless endpoint, specify the database name.

Regardless, I tried adding the `WorkgroupName` as an arg which gives me the following (expected) error

```
Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in input: \"WorkgroupName\", must be one of: ClusterIdentifier, Database, DbUser, SecretArn, Sqls, StatementName, WithEvent"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect to Redshift Serverless, you will need to use boto3 1.24.11 at the minimum. See the [changelog for boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst). Note that the error is returned from the Redshift data API which runs in the cloud and does not depend on boto3.

Comment: Where does it say that it requires 1.24.11+?
All I see is that they added this new parameter "WorkgroupName" to be used with newer clients.

Comment: @IamAshay from the page *api-change:redshift-data: [botocore] This release adds a new --workgroup-name field to operations that connect to an endpoint. **Customers can now execute queries against their serverless workgroups.***

Comment: Okay, it worked after updating the boto3 to 1.24.xx.
They should have documented it better, especially since the boto3 version present in Lambda by default does not have this functionality

Comment: @MP24, ran into this issue when testing Python Lambda function against Redshift serverless table. I wish the documentation made this clear.